# Are these 2 recursive implementations of finding if a Binary Tree are equivalent?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

Problem statement is pretty clear: "Given 2 binary trees, `t1` and `t2` where `t1 >> t2`, find if `t2` is a subtree of `t1`.

Given a very simple `Node` class:

```java
class Node {
    String val;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    // getters, setters for 
}
```

I came up with 2 different implementations, which both seem to work.

**Implementation 1**

```java
boolean isSubtree(Node t1, Node t2) {
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
        return false;

    boolean isLeftSubtree = false;
    boolean isRightSubtree = false;
    if (t1.getVal().equals(t2.getVal())) {
        isLeftSubtree = ((t1.left() == null) && (t2.left() == null)) || isSubtree(t1.left(), t2.left());
        isRightSubtree = ((t1.right() == null) && (t2.right() == null)) || isSubtree(t1.right(), t2.right());
    }

    if (isLeftSubtree && isRightSubtree)
        return true;

    return isSubtree(t1.left(), t2) || isSubtree(t1.right(), t2);
}
```

**Implementation 2**

```java
boolean isSubtree(Node t1, Node t2) {
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
        return false;

    boolean isLeftSubtree;
    boolean isRightSubtree;
    if (t1.getVal().equals(t2.getVal())) {
        isLeftSubtree = ((t1.left() == null) && (t2.left() == null)) || isSubtree(t1.left(), t2.left());
        isRightSubtree = ((t1.right() == null) && (t2.right() == null)) || isSubtree(t1.right(), t2.right());
        return isLeftSubtree && isRightSubtree;
    }

    return isSubtree(t1.left(), t2) || isSubtree(t1.right(), t2);
}
```

I have a feeling the second implementation is not correct but I was not able to make it fail with test cases I came up with.

My question is, are these 2 implementations identical and both correct given the problem? (Or are they both wrong, which would be embarrassing..)

Comment: If t1 and t2 are both null, they should also be equal I'd think. Currently if t1 is null it returns false, even if t2 is also null.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I made that part a bit messy I think. I got it covered in `isLeftSubtree = ((t1.left() == null) && (t2.left() == null)`..

Comment: I misread something, forget my comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2<sup>nd</sup> implementation is incorrect. We can't immediately return the answer as written in

`return isLeftSubtree && isRightSubtree;`

Consider this case where `tree1` is as follows:

```
             1
           /   \
          2     3
               / 
              4
               \
                1
               /
              2
             /
            3
```

and `tree2` as follows:

```
          1
         /
        2
       /
      3
```

Your code would check for equality in the root node itself and conclude to return a `false` without giving subtrees a chance to deal with it.

Also, recursive approach is a good way to check for subtree existence, but the time complexity is O(n^2) in the worst case. You could instead serialize both trees and check if serialization of tree 2 is present in serialization of tree 1.